# Multiple return for vlookup and summing up for large no. of table arrays

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have a master list as shown here

[image]

Stock lists are as below :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzaLH.png)

I'm referring stock availability from different sheets and putting vlookup in each column and then processing that data like sum or average,
for large no of sheets process gets very slow and individual vlookup formulas when sheets are more makes excel very sluggish.
any advise to do it efficiently

I have tried doing vlookup through vba but process was very slow for large data ( approx 2000 rows and 60 no of sheets)

VBA code is as follows :

Sub vlookup1()

Dim myrange As Range

item_nos = Worksheets("MASTER").UsedRange.Rows(Worksheets("MASTER").UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

For j = 3 To 3

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Stock-" & j)
lastcolumn = ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count
lastrow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    
With ws
Set myrange = .Cells(1, 1).Resize(lastrow, lastcolumn)
End With

    For i = 2 To item_nos
    
    item_tag = Worksheets("MASTER").Cells(i, 1)
    stock = ""
    
          
    On Error Resume Next
    stock = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(item_tag, myrange, 2, False)
    
    Worksheets("MASTER").Cells(i, 5 + j) = stock
    
    'i = i + 1
    
    Next i
```

Next j

End Sub

Comment: Welcome to SO. Looks like you may benefit from [Consolidate data in multiple worksheets](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/consolidate-data-in-multiple-worksheets-007ce8f4-2fae-4fea-9ee5-a0b2c9e36d9b) and you can record a macro for it

Comment: If you are on `Microsoft-365` then may use `VSTACK()` and `XLOOKUP()`.

Comment: Please share the code you tried and the VLOOKUP formulae you got. Also share a screenshot of a STOCK worksheet. Add any additional information by [editing your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74442524/edit).

Comment: If i use fixed range reference this code works extremely fast but when i define range with variable no. of rows and columns it becomes very slow